# How to put all related self-related objects in a tableview with associated section header for each relationship mapping?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a entity called "Skill". Skill has relationship mappings to itself for three different types - easier, harder, and similar.

[image]

I want to create a tableview using with 3 sections - easier, harder, and similar for a particular skill that I happen to be viewing. I am trying to determine how to create a fetch request using NSFetchedResultsController to collect all 3 of these skills into one. Here is my attempt

```
fileprivate lazy var relatedSkillsFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Skill> = {
        let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Skill> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Skill")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN self.easier OR %@ IN self.harder OR %@ IN self.similar", skill!,skill!,skill!)
        let skillFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(skill.relationshipFetchName), cacheName: nil)
        return skillFetchedResultsController
    }()
```

I was thinking - since easier is the inverse of harder and harder is the inverse of easier and similar is the inverse of similar.... I can fetch the original separately elsehow... then fetch all skills with the predicate that the main skill is in those skills harder or easier or similar.

Does this sound like the right way to do this?

I also don't know how to set the sectionNameKeyPath. Its basically would correspond to which of the three NSPredicate OR's that it matches right?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with configuring a FRC is not so much finding the `sectionNameKeyPath`, though that can be difficult, but rather in getting a sort descriptor that is consistent with the desired sections: the sort descriptors compatible with a fetch request are relatively limited.

In your case, I would be tempted to create only a single, reflexive relationship from Skill to itself (`relatedSkills`), but to add an integer attribute to the Skill entity, to represent `difficulty`.  You can decide on the scale (eg. 0-9, 0-99, whatever) and decide how close the difficulty must be (eg. +/-1, or +/-2, etc) for two skills to be judged "similar".

You can then use a predicate to select only those skills related to your chosen Skill:

```
NSPredicate(format:"ANY relatedSkills == %@", chosenSkill)
```

and add a sort descriptor based on `difficulty`.  Then define a function to determine (using the rules you decide upon) whether any given Skill is "easier", "similar", or "harder".  That function will be your `sectionNameKeyPath`.

**Update**

Well, having pondered this overnight, I realise that I was wrong.  In the above scenario, the `sectionNameKeyPath` is the difficult bit: the problem is that it depends on the currently selected Skill, but the function can take no parameters, so cannot “know” which is the currently selected skill.  Back to the drawing board....